# Kubuntu 19.10: Application Menu button on titlebar not showing

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, plasma-5

I have enabled the **Application menu button** in my Plasma settings (by dragging the "Menu" icon to the title bar, as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A75jDD38AE), but it still doesn't show up in apps which contain menu bar (such as Kate, Dolphin, Konsole and LibreOffice).

I'm talking about this one:

[image: Application menu button]

Why is that? Using [Kubuntu 19.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu) updated to [Plasma 5.18 LTS](https://kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.18.0).

Comment: You may also wish to ask in one of the KDE Support venues listed at https://kde.org/support/ for a quicker answer.

Comment: Hi, that's an old video. I'm also on Plasma 5.18 (Kubuntu 20.04) and see the Global Menu for Kate, Dolphin, and LibreOffice. Maybe you should explain in words and images what exactly you tried to do so that people don't give you advice that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @DKBose This video link was added by K7AAY, not me -- I know that now it works differently :)

Comment: @DKBose Let's be more precise - do you see Global Menu as a 3-line button, located in the titlebar? (added image illustration)

Comment: Thank you! I see the button with Konsole, Kate, Dolphin, LibreOffice Writer, Featherpad, and Mousepad but not with Firefox & Gedit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aOxe.png.

Comment: @DKBose Okay, and that's what happens on my pc: https://imgur.com/YFTk73e

Comment: @DKBose As you can see, menu button is not showing despite being enabled in Settings

Comment: Can you please try with a new user? Maybe some file has been corrupted for the existing user?

Comment: And remove the third button from the left in case that's interfering?

Comment: @DKBose I tried with a new user, and it worked! Button shows as it should. Which user files may have been corrupted, what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104628/discussion-between-dk-bose-and-emvaized).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by importing `~/.config` folder from the new KDE account to the old one.